# Installing package interactiveanimation, missing .js file

Tags: pdftex

Hey i need use the package interactiveanimation, so I install it using Miktek and everything seems ok, but when i run the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{interactiveanimation}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
I can't find file 'javascript/DocLevel.js'
```

Also the manual of the package says that there is to copy some Javascript files to "a place where Miktek can find them"

I have the DocLevel.js file. My problem is ¿Where copy it?

Comment: judging from the error putting it it in a `javascript` folder below the document would work

Comment: A lot of thanks. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error putting it it in a `javascript` folder below the document would work